# TYPO3 tx_news - How to show related news by category?

Tags: typo3, categories, tx-news

is there an easy way to show related news by category in the news detail template?
For a single news item I want to show three related news by category.

Ralf

Answer (score 5):

**News** extension does not offer such configuration for front-end plugin in TYPO3 back-end. Nevertheless you can quite easly achieve that by integrating plugin via TypoScript. You'll find more about it in [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html) for **news** extension. Anyway, this snippet might do the trick for you.

Step 1) Integrate **news** extension via TypoScript

```
lib.newsRelatedByFirstCategory = USER
lib.newsRelatedByFirstCategory {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = News
    pluginName = Pi1
    vendorName = GeorgRinger

    switchableControllerActions {
        News {
            1 = list
        }
    }

    settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
    settings {
        excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews = 1
        templateLayout = 201
        relatedView = 1
        limit = 6
        useStdWrap := addToList(categories)
        categories.current = 1
        categoryConjunction = or
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
        startingpoint = 59
    }
}
```

Step 2) Display **news** plugin via cObject in your news' extension template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.newsRelatedByFirstCategory">{newsItem.firstCategory.uid}</f:cObject>
```

It will make an instance of **news** plugin and display 6 news records from the first category to which belongs currently displayed news.

Of course you need to specify `startingpoint` and `templateLayout` to match your specific TYPO3 configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me.
You are right. I should have read the documentation in detail before.